# How to regex match every record in this s3 file?

Tags: amazon-s3, regex-group

I have an s3 file that looks like this:

```
disconnecting session |Wed, 26 May 2021 14:00:17:299|::ffff:127.0.0.1 |43162 |13514|dev |rdsdb |password |1197326263| | |0| | | | | | | 
authenticated |Wed, 26 May 2021 14:00:37:267|::ffff:10.81.74.251 |57150 |16455|analytics |some_company |password |0|TLSv1.2 |ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 |0| | | | | | | 
initiating session |Wed, 26 May 2021 14:00:37:267|::ffff:10.81.74.251 |57150 |16455|analytics |some_company |password |0|TLSv1.2 |ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 |0| | | | | | | 
disconnecting session |Wed, 26 May 2021 14:00:37:381|::ffff:10.81.74.251 |57150 |16455|analytics |some_company |password |115492|TLSv1.2 |ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 |0| | | | | | | 
authenticated |Wed, 26 May 2021 14:00:37:399|::ffff:10.81.74.251 |57154 |16456|analytics |some_company |password |0|TLSv1.2 |ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 |0| | | | | | |
```

Each record is either an authenticated, initiating, disconnecting record and represents a connection to a database. I'd like to get each record and from there, turn the record into columns where each column is separated by the | delimiter. Eventually I want to convert this file into a csv with columns. How do I first get all the records? I need to write a regex to capture each record right? What is that regex?

Comment: Looks like a CSV already, pipe delimited, no? What do you mean by "match" and "capture"? What data are you trying to get and what programming environment are you using? Thanks.

Comment: I'm using python. I basically want all 5 rows in here so that I can start manipulating each row.